# Влияние контена элемента на flex-grow

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Как сделать, чтобы при такой верстке, контент (во втором примере) не влиял на ширину элементов и при этом сохранялась "резиновость"

```css
.one, .two{
  display: flex;
}
.one__item{
  flex-grow: 10;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 20px;
}
.two__item{
  flex-grow: 10;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="one">
      <div class="one__item">1</div>
      <div class="one__item">1</div>
      <div class="one__item">1</div>
      <div class="one__item">1</div>
      <div class="one__item">1</div>
      <div class="one__item">1</div>
      <div class="one__item">1</div> 
    </div>
    <div class="two">
      <div class="two__item"></div>
      <div class="two__item"></div>
      <div class="two__item"></div>
      <div class="two__item"></div>
      <div class="two__item"></div>
      <div class="two__item"></div>
      <div class="two__item"></div>
    </div>
    <br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="one">
  <div class="one__item">133</div>
  <div class="one__item">144444</div>
  <div class="one__item">15555</div>
  <div class="one__item">1634</div>
  <div class="one__item">134</div>
  <div class="one__item">134</div>
  <div class="one__item">133</div> 
</div>
<div class="two">
  <div class="two__item"></div>
  <div class="two__item"></div>
  <div class="two__item"></div>
  <div class="two__item"></div>
  <div class="two__item"></div>
  <div class="two__item"></div>
  <div class="two__item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте параметр flex-basis: 0 (ну или любое значение в px или %, отличное от нуля)

```css
.one, .two{
  display: flex;
}
.one__item{
  flex-grow: 10;
  flex-basis: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 20px;
}
.two__item{
  flex-grow: 10;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
      <div class="one__item">1</div>
      <div class="one__item">1</div>
      <div class="one__item">1</div>
      <div class="one__item">1</div>
      <div class="one__item">1</div>
      <div class="one__item">1</div>
      <div class="one__item">1</div> 
    </div>
    <div class="two">
      <div class="two__item"></div>
      <div class="two__item"></div>
      <div class="two__item"></div>
      <div class="two__item"></div>
      <div class="two__item"></div>
      <div class="two__item"></div>
      <div class="two__item"></div>
    </div>
    <br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="one">
  <div class="one__item">133</div>
  <div class="one__item">144444</div>
  <div class="one__item">15555</div>
  <div class="one__item">1634</div>
  <div class="one__item">134</div>
  <div class="one__item">134</div>
  <div class="one__item">133</div> 
</div>
<div class="two">
  <div class="two__item"></div>
  <div class="two__item"></div>
  <div class="two__item"></div>
  <div class="two__item"></div>
  <div class="two__item"></div>
  <div class="two__item"></div>
  <div class="two__item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

В простейшем случае так (если не поможет, то надо absolute'ы раскладывать):

```css
.one, .two{
  display: flex;
}
.one__item{
  flex: 10 0 0px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 20px;
}

.two__item{
  flex: 10 0 0px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
      <div class="one__item">1</div>
      <div class="one__item">1</div>
      <div class="one__item">1</div>
      <div class="one__item">1</div>
      <div class="one__item">1</div>
      <div class="one__item">1</div>
      <div class="one__item">1</div> 
    </div>
    <div class="two">
      <div class="two__item"></div>
      <div class="two__item"></div>
      <div class="two__item"></div>
      <div class="two__item"></div>
      <div class="two__item"></div>
      <div class="two__item"></div>
      <div class="two__item"></div>
    </div>
    <br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="one">
  <div class="one__item">133</div>
  <div class="one__item">144444</div>
  <div class="one__item">15555</div>
  <div class="one__item">1634</div>
  <div class="one__item">134</div>
  <div class="one__item">134</div>
  <div class="one__item">133</div> 
</div>
<div class="two">
  <div class="two__item"></div>
  <div class="two__item"></div>
  <div class="two__item"></div>
  <div class="two__item"></div>
  <div class="two__item"></div>
  <div class="two__item"></div>
  <div class="two__item"></div>
</div>
```